# Where is the problem in my below method to determine remainder of $2^{2022} \bmod 10$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I want to determine $2^{2022} \bmod 10$.  I did  division of $2^n$  modulo $10$ regarding values of natural number $n$ as follows:
$$\begin{align*}
2^0 &\equiv 1\pmod{10}\\
2^1 &\equiv 2\pmod{10}\\
2^2 &\equiv 4\pmod{10}\\
2^3 &\equiv 8\pmod{10}\\
2^4 &\equiv 6 \pmod{10}\\
2^5 &\equiv 2 \pmod{10}.
\end{align*}$$
This implies  the period of division is $n=5k$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, which means that $2^{2022}=(2^5)^{404}\times2^2=8\bmod 10$, but in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E2022%3D+4mod+10) the remainder is $4\bmod 10$.
Where is the problem?

Comment: At $2^5$ you get only back to $2^1$ not all the way back to $2^0$; so the period is 4, not 5.

Comment: the powers of $2$ modulo $2$ are $1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...$

Comment: Not $2$ and $10$ are not relatively prime.  You can use $2^{4 + k}\equiv 2^k\pmod {10}$ (if $k > 0$) but you can't reason you have a $2^k \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ as there is not so $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't include $2^0 \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$ in your period of division count as it only comes up once. The repeating digits are $2, 4, 8, 6$ instead.

So you should do $2^{2022} = 2^4\times 2^2 = 16\times 4 \equiv 6 \times 4 = 24 \equiv \boxed{4 \pmod{10}}$ $\blacksquare$.

---

Or if you want to do it your way by splitting the $2022$ power instead of my way which is by using the repeating units digits, you could do the following:

$2^{2022} = (2^5)^{404} \times 2^2 \equiv (2)^{404} \times 2^2 \equiv 6 \times 4 \equiv 24 \equiv \boxed{4 \pmod{10}}\blacksquare$.

Eventually, you would have to use the repeating units digits. Your made a mistake when you said $(2^5)^{404} \times 2^2 \equiv 8 \pmod{10}$.

---

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, for $n\color{blue}{>0}, 2^{n+\color{red}4}\equiv2^{n} \bmod 10$,

so, yes, $2^{2022}\equiv2^2=4\bmod10$.

Answer (score 0):

Because $2$ and $10$ are not relatively prime, you never return to $1$ ever.

Instead, the period returns *not* to $2^0 = 1$, but to $2^5 \equiv 2^1 \equiv 2 \pmod {10}$.  That is a period from $1\to 5$ is a period of $5-1 = 4$. This isn't a period for $0 \to 5$ for a period of $5-0 = 0$.

We can still do $2^a \equiv 2^b \pmod {10}$, if $b \equiv a\pmod 4$, provided neither of $b$ or $a$ is actually equal to $0$.   $2^0 = 1$, but for any other $2^a; a\equiv 0 \pmod 4; a > 0$, we have $2^a\equiv 16\pmod {10}$

As $2^{2022} = 2^{505\cdot 4 + 2}$ , we have $2^{2022} \equiv 2^2 \equiv 4 \pmod {10}$